# How to call Application_Model_ContactModel on controller

Tags: php, model, call

I have a problem when I call Application_Model_ContactModel from controller

This is my model code
[image]

This is my controller code
[image]

And this is my folder
[image]

When I run it, it always returns the message "Class 'Application\Model\Application_Model_ContactModel' not found"

Comment: I am found solution.

Comment: First, Move folder Model to folder src

Comment: Second, rename class name same model file name

Comment: Third, on controller, $test = new \Application\Model\ContactController();